# why is Instance:new function not on Instance API page (roblox)

Tags: roblox

I look at Instance API page, but It didn't have Instace:new function in function part.
(https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Instance)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the instance class, what you're looking for is probably the Instance datatype
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/Instance